# Formik tRPC error "Expected string, received null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, trpc.io

I am using Formik in my Nextjs app along with tRPC. When I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
TRPCClientError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "null",
    "path": [
      "user",
      "handle"
    ],
    "message": "Expected string, received null"
  }
]
```

Here is my form:

```
const tenantMutation = trpc.tenant.createTenant.useMutation();
  const CreateTenantSchema = z.object({
    organization: z
      .string()
      .min(3, "Too short!")
      .max(60, "Too long!")
      .regex(organizationRegex, "Only alphanumeric characters are allowed"),
    handle: z
      .string()
      .min(3, "Too short!")
      .max(40, "Too long!")
      .regex(handleRegex, "Only alphanumeric characters are allowed"),
  });
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      organization: "",
      handle: "",
    },
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      //   if (!user.data) return;
      await tenantMutation.mutateAsync({
        name: values.organization,
        handle: values.handle,
        user: user.data as UserSchema,
      });
    },
    validationSchema: toFormikValidationSchema(CreateTenantSchema),
  });

  return (
    <div className="grid gap-10 grid-cols-1 mt-4 text-center">
      <p className="text-2xl font-medium">Welcome aboard!</p>
      <p className="text-lg font-medium">
        Looks like you need to create or join an organization.
      </p>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} className="space-y-4 mx-auto">
        <VTextfield
          id="organization"
          name="organization"
          type="text"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          label={"Organization"}
          placeholder={"My Company"}
          value={formik.values.organization}
          errorMessage={formik.errors.organization}
        />
        <VTextfield
          id="handle"
          name="handle"
          type="text"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          label={"Handle"}
          placeholder={"jsmith23"}
          value={formik.values.handle}
          errorMessage={formik.errors.handle}
        />

        <VButton
          text="Create organization"
          type="submit"
          classNames={["w-[290px] mx-auto"]}
          disabled={
            (formik.errors.handle !== undefined &&
              formik.errors.handle.length > 0) ||
            (formik.errors.organization !== undefined &&
              formik.errors.organization.length > 0)
          }
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I console.log the input values I get the correct values and types. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?